# Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery - data studio/my sql connector error

Tags: mysql, looker-studio

I have a query that is running just fine in MySQL Workbench but am getting a data studio-related error once I try to run it in mysql connector within data studio. I’ve been trying to google around and ask on SO and data studio message boards for some ideas, but am not getting many ideas. Most of the responses I’ve found are related to Java.

My query:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE cte_most_recent_record
    SELECT
    leeds_new.leenk_ladder_history.member_id as member_id,
    max(leeds_new.leenk_ladder_history.date_trigger_event) AS date_trigger_event_max
    FROM leeds_new.leenk_ladder_history
    WHERE leeds_new.leenk_ladder_history.ladder_change = 1 and leeds_new.leenk_ladder_history.ladder_advocacy is not NULL
    group by leeds_new.leenk_ladder_history.member_id;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE cte_most_recent_record_date_ladder
    select 
    lh.member_id,
    lh.ladder_advocacy,
    lh.date_trigger_event

    from leeds_new.leenk_ladder_history as lh 
        inner join
            cte_most_recent_record as cte_rr on lh.member_id = cte_rr.member_id
            and lh.date_trigger_event = cte_rr.date_trigger_event_max
            limit 100;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE cte_ladder_counts_before
    select 
        ladder_advocacy,
        count(ladder_advocacy) as ladder_counts_before

    from cte_most_recent_record_date_ladder
        where date_trigger_event < date('2018-01-01')
        group by ladder_advocacy;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE cte_ladder_counts_after
    select 
        ladder_advocacy,
        count(ladder_advocacy) as ladder_counts_after

    from cte_most_recent_record_date_ladder
        where date_trigger_event > date('2018-01-01')
        group by ladder_advocacy;

select
    cte_ladder_counts_before.ladder_advocacy,
    cte_ladder_counts_before.ladder_counts_before,
    ladder_counts_after,
    ladder_counts_before - ladder_counts_after

from cte_ladder_counts_before
    inner join cte_ladder_counts_after on cte_ladder_counts_before.ladder_advocacy = cte_ladder_counts_after.ladder_advocacy; 

drop table cte_most_recent_record;
drop table cte_most_recent_record_date_ladder;
drop table cte_ladder_counts_before;
drop table cte_ladder_counts_after;
```

The error:

```
Sorry, we encountered an error and were unable to complete your request.

Failed to execute connection with error: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().
Error ID: 24721465
```

I believe that this has something to do with that I have multiple tables within the same query - because I can run the query with just one of the select statements? But I am not sure if there are other data studio things I should be aware of.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a bit late for an answer, but just in case someone needs this in the future. I ran into the same issue today. And the answer is quite frustrating as it is easy to solve.

You're using a `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` sentence (as I was doing too). Then I realized that DataStudio can't process that sentence. (Apparently, it can't do multi-queries either).

So my workaround was to actually CREATE the table in my database, not as a temporary one. (effective but not clean at all)... and delete the `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` sentence in my query. worked like a charm but on the dark side, now I have an useless table in my database just to process that query.

Hope it helps, kind regards.